# Supported methods: PATCH, DELETE

Tags: laravel, post, routes, methods

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to update an item quantity in a cart, so I set this route:

```
Route::patch('/item/{rowId}', [CartController::class, 'update'])->name('item.update');
```

and my form code is like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('item-update', $items->rowId)}}" method="PUT">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    <span>
        <button type="submit"><span style="color:blue">
         Mettre à jour le panier</span></button>
    </span>
</form>
```

I tried everything, but still can't get to the update method in my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $rowId)
{
    //
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your route says `patch`, your method says `put`. They are not the same.

Comment: what should I name them both ? `put` or `patch`

Comment: `method="PUT"` is invalid. Should be `method="POST"`

Comment: what about the route ?

Comment: Either one will work. PUT and PATCH are both fine, Laravel supports both. Which one you use is up to you. There's a guidance somewhere on what each should be used for, but it's not a hard and fast rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Route::patch` and `method="PUT"` is not wrong.
But `Route::patch` and `method="POST"` is accepted practice.

Real issue in here is route names are not match `...->name('item.update');` and `{{ route('item-update',...`

change `route('item-update')` to `route('item.update')`